# Android Failed to create signed apk with error code -1

Tags: android, proguard

After implementing Proguard, it gives following error on exporting the apk.

**Error:**

Duplicate zip entry [android_6861407322325970495.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]

I am using in app billing in my project.

Comment: What is your java build path / export settings?

Comment: nothing, just some libraries i am using in the project. its all the default settings, i didn't change anything. let me know what you want to look, i can paste that here

Comment: Any cross / duplicate reference to a same library(jar)? Like YourApp references JarA and JarB, but library project JarB also exports JarA.

Comment: didn't find the issue, but i sort of rewrite the progaurd config file and the error disappears. (strange) may be progaurd file was not configured properly